# How to change location of the buttons on tkinter pack

Tags: python, tkinter, button

My buttons are shown in the order of "previous image" and "next image" on the left side and "exit" and "next set" on the right side. I would like to have the next set button still be on the right side overall but be to the left of the exit button. So I would like the "next set" and "exit" buttons to switch spots.

I was also wondering if it was possible to show the exit button on the bottom right of the screen. The second image I provided shows what happens whenever I use `.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)`, as the exit button doesn't really go underneath the whole image.

[image]

[image]

```
fram = tk.Frame(self)
tk.Button(fram, text="Previous Image", bg="green", command=self.prev).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
tk.Button(fram, text="  Next Image  ", command=self.next).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
tk.Button(fram, text="            Next set              ", command=self._load_dataset).pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
tk.Button(fram, text="  Exit  ", command=self.destroy, fg = "grey").pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
tk.Label(fram, textvariable=self.clickStatus, font='Helvetica 18 bold').pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
# inside or outside
fram.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCFGZ.png)

Comment: If you want the `Exit` button at the bottom right corner, try making it the child of `self` instead of `fram` and use `.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, anchor='e')`.  Also use `width` option instead of padding spaces around the text of those buttons.

Comment: Hey there, welcome to Stack Overflow. I see that you tried your best to explain what you want. But it would be really great if you write what the images are in the image descriptions (for example, "this is how it is now" and "this is what I want"). just hit edit and change "enter image description here".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I would like the "next set" and "exit" buttons to switch spots.

The packer works by placing widgets along one of the sides of the unallocated space in the master widget. Order matters, since each widget causes the unallocated space to change. For example, if you want a widget on the far right side of a frame, you should pack it on the right before you pack any other widgets.

In your case, the solution is as simple as changing the order in which you call pack.

```
tk.Button(fram, text="  Exit  ", command=self.destroy, fg = "grey").pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
tk.Button(fram, text="            Next set              ", command=self._load_dataset).pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
```

> I was also wondering if it was possible to show the exit button on the bottom right of the screen.

Yes, it's possible. The simplest solution is to divide your window into three areas: a top set of buttons, a buttom set of buttons, and the image area.

For example, the following code creates three frames for these three areas, and uses `pack` to arrange them. Once you do these, it becomes trivial to add buttons to the top and bottom frames in whatever order you want.

```
top_frame = tk.Frame(self)
bottom_frame = tk.Frame(self)
image_frame = tk.Frame(self)

top_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
bottom_frame.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
image_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

exit_button = tk.Button(bottom_frame, text="Exit", ...)
exit_button.pack(side="right")

previous_button = tk.Button(top_frame, text="Previous Image", ...)
next_button = tk.Button(top_frame, text="Next Image", ...)
next_set_button = tk.Button(top_frame, text="Next Set", ...)

previous_button.pack(side="left")
next_button.pack(side="left")
next_set_button.pack(side="right")
```

Another way to do this is to make all of the buttons a child of `self` which makes it easy to define them all in the same block of code, and use the `in_` parameter to specify where they go.

```
exit_button = tk.Button(self, text="Exit", ...)
previous_button = tk.Button(self, text="Previous Image", ...)
next_button = tk.Button(self, text="Next Image", ...)
next_set_button = tk.Button(self, text="Next Set", ...)

exit_button.pack(in_=bottom_frame, side="right")
previous_button.pack(in_=top_frame, side="left")
next_button.pack(in_=top_frame, side="left")
next_set_button.pack(in_=top_frame, side="right")
```

For the definitive description of how the packer works, see [Packer Algorithm](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.11/TkCmd/pack.htm#M27) in the official tk documentation.

Comment: Hi thank you for your help! I got an error saying 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack' for 'exit_button.pack(side="right")' line of code. I added the image of my code into the original post

Comment: @idkman: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1101750/7432

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if there was a way to change the size of the text or the buttons to make them bigger?

Comment: @newtocoding: yes. That's all covered in existing documentation and several online tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to pack is to use the button's grid attributes to place them in the frame.

I have used separate frames for placing buttons in my app:

```
frame_buttons = ttk.Frame(tab_details)
frame_buttons.grid(column = 0, row = 3, sticky = tk.EW)
frame_buttons.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
frame_buttons.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)
button_process = ttk.Button(frame_buttons, text = 'Process', command = text_to_xml)
button_process.grid(column = 0, row = 0) # in the centre of the left column
button_clear = ttk.Button(frame_buttons,text = 'Clear', command = clear_entries)
button_clear.grid(column = 1, row = 0) # in the centre of the right column
```

The grid is described here in the TkDocs site:
[TkDocs](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html)